# Facebook send button disappeared after sometime

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I just added a Facebook Send plugin on my site. Everything worked perfect but after sometimes the Facebook send button disappeared. When page is reloaded, send button appear again.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.google.com" ></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=519408*********";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

There is one more problem with the Facebook Send plugin,the auto generated `<ifrme>` tags height and width are 1000px. If I inspect the elements this code will appear.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe name="f3ff0f29fc" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0"  allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:send Facebook Social Plugin" src="" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: which method do you use? the iframe, or the xfbml? the iframe is not supported for send button https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Comment: also, your ending `script` tag is broken. it should be `</script>` and not `/script`

Comment: I am using xfbml method.If you see your link ,there is a horizontal scroll .This scroll will appear for ifram width.

Comment: then again, in the xfbml method there is no iframe.

Comment: I told u that when i am inspect the send button this iframe tag will appear

Comment: if you open this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/ for 3 minute ,you will see that the send button will disappear.

Comment: on win 7 with chrome it does not disapear even after 10 min (tested).
Did you add `xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"` to your html tag?

Comment: You have to be logged out of Facebook in order to disappear, I tested it on both Chrome and Firefox in OS X

Answer (score 3):

I agree with other comments here, this behavior is consistent and therefore must be a feature of FB. The button only disappears when not logged in to FB.

Here are 2 ways to circumvent this issue:

1.

One way is ofcourse to use the **SEND button** with the *send* attribute set to *true* (in HTML5 code style, add the attribute: `data-send="true"`). This send button will NOT disappear.

2.

Another way is to set a css rule as such (for HTML5 style):

> div.fb-send iframe {width: 60px !important; height: 30px !important;}

The width & height may be any value you wish. you may want to add a few more pixels for width, to accommodate for a language that translates the "send" word to more than 4 letters.

Comment: option 2 fix the disappearance of the send button but doesn't display the dialog window once you click on it.

Comment: @JoaoLeme , make sure ALL ancestor elements have the `overflow:visible;` css directive, well at least any with smaller dimension than the dimension of the popup iframe + send button.

Comment: it is not possible to have an overflowed iframe

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS:

```
div.fb-send iframe { min-width: 59px !important; min-height: 20px !important; }
```

Then also add **data-width="59" data-height="20"** to the .fb-send div to set the starting iframe style height, avoinding the 1000px height otherwise, that creates an invisible layer disabling buttons below it.

```
<div class="fb-send" data-width="59" data-height="20" data-href="http://example.com"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the link @Dementic posted: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

Look at the example button under "Get a Send button" where you can style your button. Watch it - this too dissapears after 40 seconds.

I had a simular problem with the invisible iframe overlapping, so I have added a width to the particular `li` where i have my [send] button untill i have time to investigate further.

I set the [send] buttons up a while ago and they were fine, so FB must of changed something recently.

I am unsure to why on my sites and on the facebook dev link above that the 'send' button dissapaears after 40 seconds...

Comment: I noticed this behavior when I'm not logged in to FB. Also, a horizontal scroll bar appears on the page. They really messed it up... Hope FB fixes it soon

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you did something wrong while trying to implement the FB Send plugin.
Your `script` tag is broken, and you are using an `iframe` which is not supported for the Send button.

You should try and create a new one at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

make sure you follow the instructions and copy the code correctly.